# Cannot connect to ssh server

Tags: ssh, security, plesk

I am having trouble connecting to my ssh server. It responds with a lengthy error message about no network etc. but it is the last message that concerns me:

> Sometimes, such troubles can be caused by a misconfigured firewall.

How can I check the firewall if I cannot connect to ssh? I am running plesk 11.5 control panel and CentOS 6. Is this something I can do from plesk?

I can see that the firewall in plesk is set to allow all for ssh, but I cannot see way to disable the firewall to test ssh connection. Can this be done from plesk?

It is driving me absolutely bananas and I would be grateful if someone could shed some light as to how I can proceed.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: When I connect to an unreachable host with ssh, I just get a message along the lines of: `ssh: connect to host 192.168.255.4 port 22: Connection timed out`. That's the full error I get. What exactly are you doing to get this message, and what's the full content of it?

Comment: @derobert Just trying to establish a coonection using ssh client. Was working fine this morning. The first is about the host being unreachable. That is working ok. The second is, Host may be down or network connection. The host is not down. Which led me to the option i highlighted in my question. I think the server has been stopped, but I cannot see way to start it from plesk. I have root access to server. thanks

Comment: Can you include the actual "lengthy error message" that you get? Including the error message will help people actually diagnose the problem.

Comment: @Greg I have included the message in my comment above. Thanks

Comment: This error message is produced by a Windows program called **SSH Secure Shell**. You might want to check the firewall on your Windows system, or if you're on campus, their firewall, too.